# Karma stacktraces showing javascript line numbers instead of coffeescript

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, coffeescript, stack-trace, karma-runner

I'm running some Karma tests using Intellij and one of them is failing. The stacktrace I get from the output seems to be giving me the lines in the Javascript and not the CoffeeScript, making it much harder for me to debug. Is there any way I can get the stacktrace lines to show up in their proper Coffeescript format?

Answer (score 1):

**1. Preprocessor Configuration**

Make sure you have your preprocessor settings enabled in karma.conf.js.

```
preprocessors: {
  '**/*.coffee': ['coffee']
},
coffeePreprocessor: {
  options: {
    bare: true,
    sourceMap: true
  },
  transformPath: function(path) {
    return path.replace(/\.js$/, '.coffee');
  }
}
```

If your karma.conf is also in coffeescript (i.e. karma.conf.coffee), it would look like this:

```
preprocessors: '**/*.coffee': ['coffee']

coffeePreprocessor:
  options:
    bare: true
    sourceMap: true
  transformPath: (path) ->
    path.replace /\.js$/, '.coffee'
```

---

**2. Use Karma's Default Browser**

Make sure you're using "Chrome" as your Karma browser (not PhantomJS). This is also specified in your karma config.

While PhantomJS does allow for mapping JS line numbers to Coffeescript line numbers, [it doesn't do so properly at this time](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-coffee-preprocessor/issues/12).

```
browsers: ['Chrome']
```